# Scaling for spring boot application using spring cloud

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices

I am using spring boot with Kubernetes and Eventhub. To connect with Azure Eventhub i use spring cloud stream. What is the math to determine the number of pods assuming non reactive spring boot application with apache tomcat?

Edit 1: to reframe my question, how do you factor in spring boot performance , request rate , user count, etc while scaling the pods?

Answer (score 1):

In general the number of pods can be managed with a Deployment in Kubernetes. For more information you can see here [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/). In a Deployment you tell Kubernetes how many Replicas you want, which means how many Pods should be running. I don't know what you mean with non reactive spring boot application with apache tomcat. I also don't know about spring cloud stream.